# mongoDB: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, exception

I am trying to write a little test-programm with different Databases. MongoDB is one of them and it worked perfectly fine until last Friday, even though I didn't change anything in the java code of my MongoDB class.

System: I use an ubuntu 14.04 VM with the package mongo-org. The version of mongo is 3.0.5.

I also run MariaDB, PostgreSQL and Cassandra on the VM.
As a Client, I have windows 7 and Eclipse.

The connection and the test work perfectly fine with the other 3 databases.

And I can run the "mongo" client on ubuntu as well.

But when I try out the Java Test of MongoDB, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:52)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:115)
    at de.motza.database.impl.DatabaseImplMongoDB.connect(DatabaseImplMongoDB.java:197)
    at de.motza.database.impl.DatabaseImplMongoDB.instantiate(DatabaseImplMongoDB.java:207)
    at de.motza.test.History_Log.testNewDatabase(History_Log.java:86)
    at de.motza.test.History_Log.main(History_Log.java:66)
```

The part of the java Class, where the Exception occurs:

```
private static String dbHost = "10.158.251.251";
private static int dbPort = 27017;
private static String dbName = "history_log";
private static MongoClient mongoClient = null;
[...]
@Override
    public void connect() {
        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(dbHost, dbPort);
            db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }

    }
```

I read about the disk-space, but I habe 12 GB free in my VM, so I do not think that this is the problem. I ran apt-get upgrade, but it didn't change anything either. I also reinstalled mongoDb, but nothing changed. 
I also tried to recompile, but nothing changed there either.

Does anybody have any advice?

ADDITION:

Here you find the library tab of my project. I use multiple databases, so I marked the ones important for MongoDB
[image: the library tab of my project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for a [IncompatibleClassChangeError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.10) you get is that a Mongo library binary has changed (for whatever reason) and now your earlier compiled test code isn't any more compatible with the library. I would suggest to recompile your test code and try again.

Comment: I tried to clean up the project to do that @Sergey Pauk , but it didn't help. is there another way to force eclipse to recompile everything?

Comment: considering eclipse: is it a maven-based (or some other dependency framework) project or do you import all the libraries manually?

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of your project's JavaBuildPath/Libraries tab?

Comment: I added the screenshot and marked the packages important for MongoDB

Comment: Try to remove `bson-2.3.jar` for a while and see if the code works. `mongo-java-driver` comes with it's own built-in version of bson. UPDATE: i've just checked with maven build that `mongo-java-driver` doesn't have a transient dependency on `bson` meaning that it has all it needs already built-in.

Comment: One guess about why was it working before is that the import order was different so that Eclipse loaded 'right' versions of classes.